# Salesforce Static Resource Javascript And CSS

Tags: javascript, css, salesforce, visualforce, apex

i have a requirement where i need to create a SF installable and i am trying to keep as few Static Resources as possible. In fact, i am trying to have just one BIG static resource. But i am facing a problem. I have successfully put all the css files in one large file and i have accessed the the files within it in the following way:

```
<apex:Stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryResources, 'First.css')}"/>
<apex:Stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryResources, 'Second.css')}"/>
<apex:Stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryResources, 'Third.css')}"/>
<apex:Stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryResources, 'Fourth.css')}"/>
```

If in the same file (i.e. JqueryResources) if i keep few javascript files, i am unable to access these files as:

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryResources, 'Javascript.js')}"/>
```

I currently making it work like this

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.JavascriptResource}"/>
```

where JavascriptResource is name of the stand alone static resource containing Javascript.js. So how do i fix this??

Answer (score 3):

This should be working for you.  I've been able to do exactly what you are doing successfully.  My suggestion would be this.

Here's my apex code:

`<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.MyResources, 'test.min.css')}"/>`

Find the code that is generated on the actual page:

`<link class="user" href="/resource/23423423340/MyResources/test.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Copy that link/href into a new window.  It should bring up your CSS that is loading correctly.  Then you can strip away the CSS file name and you should be left with:

`https://srm--devfull--c.cs12.visual.force.com/resource/23423423340/MyResources/`

If you go there it will then prompt you to download the static resource as a .zip file.  You can open that and see if in fact there is a `Javascript.js` file in the root of that folder or if it is elsewhere.  I've had to do this because I upload all my resources (CSS,JS,Fonts) as one large static resources with several children directories containing them.  Doing this helps me check my sanity and has usually worked in solving my problem.

Let me know if once you download the static resource if you can see your `.js` files in the root of that directory.